# Remove default nonexistent footer links

Tags: user-interface, mediawiki

I have a problem with my MediaWiki installation on a local network. I'm using MediaWiki in German. There are several footer links in my wiki, that throw a 404 error. For example in the footer there's a link `Impressum` (in English: Disclaimer). It points to `*NameOfMyWiki*:Impressum` which does not exist.

When I go to `MediaWiki:Disclaimers`, then a Disclaimer shows up, it's the page that should be behind `*wgSitename*:Impressum`. I don't think it's intended that I have to point the disclaimer link to `MediaWiki:Disclaimers`.

Another behaviour that probably is based on the same problem is, that a user gets a 404 on his own user page, when the user page is still empty/not already created (clicking on the link on the top right next to settings). When another user edits the user page of the first user, the first user then can access and edit it, too. But not when it's still empty/not defined.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [text of the footer links](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFooter#Customizing_the_Built-in_items) comes from the interface messages `MediaWiki:Privacy`, `MediaWiki:Aboutsite` and `MediaWiki:Disclaimers`.  To disable one or more of these links, **set the corresponding link text to a single hyphen** (`-`).

Alternatively, since MediaWiki 1.17, you can also modify the footer by [defining a hook in your LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFooter#Add_links_to_the_footer).

Ps. For anyone interested in going to all the way to the source, the code that handles these links is in the [Skin::footerLink()](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/Skin.php?view=markup&pathrev=112395#l941) method.  The practice of disabling various interface features by setting the corresponding message to `-` is actually pretty common (though not universal) in MediaWiki; completely blank messages are treated a bit weirdly for historical reasons, so `-` is commonly used as a stand-in for "no value".

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that you were also asking a second question about user pages.  To answer that question better, let me start by describing how MediaWiki *should* be treating non-existent pages:

- When MediaWiki sees a wikilink (most, though not necessarily all, links in the navigation menus are also handled the same way) pointing to a non-existent page, it creates what is known as a [redlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aRedlink).  These links are styled differently from normal links (typically they're colored red, hence the name) and point to an URL that looks something [like this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Like_this_one&action=edit&redlink=1), with the parameters `action=edit` (making it a special kind of edit link) and `redlink=1`.
- When a user clicks such a link, MediaWiki first checks that the page hasn't been created in the mean time, *and*, if it hasn't been, that the user is allowed to create and edit it:

  1. If the page exists, the user is just redirected to the normal view URL for the page.
  2. If the page doesn't exist, and the user is not allowed to create it, they're also redirected to the normal view URL, which then returns an HTTP 404 status code and a message saying that the page does not exist.  (This is what will happen if you click the "like this one" link above, unless you happen to be an admin on Wikipedia.)
  3. Finally, if the page doesn't exist but the user is allowed to create it, MediaWiki just treats the URL like a normal edit link and shows the edit form.

It looks like, for some reason, new users clicking the link to their own user page on your wiki are hitting case 2 above instead of the expected case 3.  This might be a [user rights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights) issue: in particular, you should check that normal logged-in users (group `user`) on your wiki have the `createpage` permission.

If you want to allow normal users to create *only* their own user pages, there are ways to do that, but all that I know of involve either installing an [extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aUser_rights_extensions) or writing your own [`getUserPermissionsErrors`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/getUserPermissionsErrors) hook.  I can give you some examples of how to do that if you want, but it takes a bit of coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. It's not quite easy to understand the concept of how a wiki works (namespaces, links in the footer e.g.), when you come from _normal_ CMS like Wordpress. The problem was, that in the sidebar the links weren't redlinks. I had to search for the pages and create them as they weren't found. After that, it worked as intended. About the user rights: A user has the permission to create a page. I'll try it with the extension you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Those links are placeholders that you might want to fill in. They are provided so you can easily fill-in some important parts of your new wiki.

See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer for a complete list.

There is actually no setting to disable them.

Comment: Hi, hashar, and welcome to StackOverflow! :)  Your answer is otherwise excellent, but the last sentence is wrong: there _are_ ways to disable these links, even just by editing MediaWiki: messages.

Comment: Thanks!  I have only tested blanking the page which is obviously wrong since MediaWiki will then fallback to getting the message from the PHP file.  Your addition to the Manual:Footer page is right: just add an hyphen -

Comment: With the help of you both I now understand how to edit these links. It took me a long time to understad that each link text is defined on its own `MediaWiki:` page. It actually says in Manual:Footer that you should use a hyphen :D

Comment: @Purr: To be fair to hashar, it didn't say that when he posted his answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The link mentioned by **Ilmari Karonen** above:

> Alternatively, since MediaWiki 1.17, you can also modify the footer by
>   [defining a hook in your LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3AFooter#Add_links_to_the_footer).

...shows how to add links to the built-in list of footer links.  What it does NOT show is how to remove the existing built-in footer links, which is what the original question was.

Turns out it is a simple addition to the referenced hook solution.  You just need to discard the existing footer links in the template array.

Most folks will not only want to remove the built-in footer links but also add their own.  In the spirit of StackOverflow, here is a complete example solution that does both (this is from an existing Wiki...)

This works in mediawiki-1.29.2 but it will probably work in many older versions too.  Put this code in your LocalSettings.php file (I put it at the bottom) to remove the existing footer links and add your own:

```
# Remove all existing footer links and add my own
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = function( $sk, &$tpl ) {

        # IMPORTANT:  this is the secret sauce - remove all existing footer links
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'] = array();

        # To add new footer links to local wiki pages:
        #
        # 1) You MUST create your new pages in your (Main) namespace first, for example:
        #
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/About_Us
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/Contact_Us
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/Disclaimer
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/Download
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/Privacy_Policy
        #
        # 2) You MUST then create each of these pages in your MediaWiki namespace:
        #
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/MediaWiki:Aboutpage 
        #               - Insert 1 line, with "About Us" (no quotes)
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/MediaWiki:Contactpage 
        #               - Insert 1 line, with "Contact Us" (no quotes)
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/MediaWiki:Disclaimerpage 
        #               - Insert 1 line, with "Disclaimer" (no quotes)
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/MediaWiki:Downloadpage 
        #               - Insert 1 line, with "Download" (no quotes)
        #       http://<your-site>/wiki/index.php/MediaWiki:Privacypage 
        #               - Insert 1 line, with "Privacy Policy" (no quotes)
        #
        # 3) Add new footer links like this:

        $tpl->set( 'aboutpage', $sk->footerLink( 'aboutpage', 'aboutpage' ) );
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'aboutpage';
        $tpl->set( 'contactpage', $sk->footerLink( 'contactpage', 'contactpage' ) );
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'contactpage';
        $tpl->set( 'disclaimerpage', $sk->footerLink( 'disclaimerpage', 'disclaimerpage' ) );
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'disclaimerpage';
        $tpl->set( 'downloadpage', $sk->footerLink( 'downloadpage', 'downloadpage' ) );
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'downloadpage';
        $tpl->set( 'privacypage', $sk->footerLink( 'privacypage', 'privacypage' ) );
        $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'privacypage';

        return true;
};
```

**IMPORTANT**: Don't forget to follow the instructions and create your own pages and the corresponding MediaWiki redirects, or your links may not show or they may be broken.